# Input type time with angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs, time

According to the Docs input[time]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

it should be enough to use the input type time and bind it to a date oject, however it doesn't work as I'd expect it.

```
<input ng-model="time" type="time" placeholder="HH:mm" min="08:00" max="17:00" required >
```

and

```
$scope.time = new Date();
```

as a Result I'd like to see just the HH:mm within the input field.

Here's a jsfiddle to play around:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7314/

Comment: Use this one https://github.com/randallmeeker/ps-input-time

Answer (score 3):

I think you need at least **Angular 1.3.0 beta** for this to work, as it looks like it was introduced then.

[Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta1-retractable-eyebrow-2014-03-07):

> ...
>
> ## Features
>
> **input**: support types date, time, datetime-local, month, week
> ([46bd6dc8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/46bd6dc88de252886d75426efc2ce8107a5134e9), [#5864](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5864))
> ....

Comment: I tried to update my jsfiddle with the latest beta relaese but didn't seem to work :(

Comment: @80leaves this one should work. Added it as an `external resource` to the left. http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7322/

Comment: thanks, but I'm experiencing a wierd behaviour. In Firefox the input displays the placeholder HH:mm and in Chrome --:--. Changing the value to let's say 12:00 the variable {{test}} is updated properly, but I can't initialize it. Can you see the same behaviour?

Comment: Formatting your date before make it working for me : $scope.time = $filter("date")(new Date(), 'HH:mm'); http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10464

Comment: @JulCh your solution works well until version 1.4.5 in which it is broken

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that, follow my code, 
http://plnkr.co/edit/60aiH0eJ8ee0FlEsQE2m?p=info

Basically i use momentjs, and set seconds and milliseconds to zero, that way browser will not render that.

```
moment().second(0).milliseconds(0).toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use input="time" with angularJS and bind it using ng-model directive

HTML: `<input type="time" ng-model="myTime"/>`

in the controller, we assign time came from database to date a new object

```
$scope.myTime = new Date(response.data.start_time);
```

this will parse the full date as a time HH:MM:SS Successfully

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.time = new Date();` in your code to:

```
var d = new Date();
$scope.time = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
```

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/bitsmith/asjv8ycq/1/

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Element Directive input[time] is used to create HTML time input with time validation and transformation.

The input must be provided in the format ISO-8601, i.e local time format HH:mm:ss, for example 15:35:10

The data model must be a Date Object, timezones used to read/write Date instance are defined using ngModel
**Syntax**

```
 <input type="time"
       ng-model="string"
       [name="string"]
       [min="string"]
       [max="string"]
       [required="string"]
       [ng-required="string"]
       [ng-change="string"]>
```

Use following code to bind time and for getting other attribute related to input type time.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>AngularJS Directives : input[time]</title>
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <style>
      b{font-family:Papyrus; color:#fa4b2a; font-size: 20px;} 
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="timeDemo">
  <script>
 angular.module('timeDemo', [])
   .controller('timeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.sample = {
       value: new Date(1999, 0, 1, 15, 30, 0)
     };
   }]);
</script>
<form name="demoForm" ng-controller="timeController as timeCtrl">
   <label for="sampleInput">Select a time from 6 am to 6 pm</label>
   <input type="time" id="sampleInput" name="input" ng-model="sample.value"
       placeholder="HH:mm:ss" min="06:00:00" max="18:00:00" required />
  <!-- min 6 am and max 6 pm i.e 18:00 -->
   <div role="alert">
     <span class="error" ng-show="demoForm.input.$error.required">
        Input is Required!</span>
     <!-- Required Error  -->
     <span class="error" ng-show="demoForm.input.$error.time">
       Input Date is  not Valid!</span>
    <!-- Validation Error -->
     
   </div>
  <i>value = <b>{{sample.value | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.input.$valid = <b>{{demoForm.input.$valid}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.input.$error = <b>{{demoForm.input.$error}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.$valid = <b>{{demoForm.$valid}}</b></i><br/>
  <i>demoForm.$error.required = <b>{{!!demoForm.$error.required}}</b></i><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will ensure your input always has HH:mm format.

```
$scope.time = return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
  date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
```

Additionally, a function can be written in the controller end to format all Date values to be fed in time input

```
getFormatDate = function (val) { // assuming val is date like "/Date(946673340000)/"
 if (val != undefined) {
    date = new Date(val.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); // creating a date object from val
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
  date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
 }
}
```