# input [type=time] expected to be a date

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input like this :

```
 <input type="time" ng-model="reunion.startHour" name="time"
        placeholder="HH:mm:ss"
        min="08:00:00" max="20:00:00" 
        class="form-control"
        id="time" required />
```

and I'm getting data from the server where the object has a field `time=08:00:00`. And I want the input to set to that value when loading the page.But I get this error :

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `08:00:00` to be a date

Now I've tried this :

```
$filter('date')(new Date(data.startHour), 'HH:mm');
```

but I got `invalid date`.

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: `<input type="date">`?

Comment: new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

Comment: From angularDocs => The model must always be a Date object, otherwise AngularJS will throw an error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus but I want it to be time input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input type time with angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984681/input-type-time-with-angular-js)

Comment: Works with AngularJS 1.6. See the [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/O0cMSoJr0UwE2ka6NecL?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately JS doesn't support dates with just a time. `HH:mm` is not a valid date format: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

You can either handle it manually or use a fake date for the date part you don't care about.

(I tried to find a good time-object solution for you, but I don't see much out there. Hopefully someone else has a smoother solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Works in AngularJS 1.6

```
<input type="time" ng-model="startHour" name="time"
       placeholder="HH:mm:ss"
       min="08:00:00" max="20:00:00"
       class="form-control"
       id="time" required />

<br><p ng-show="startHour">{{startHour | date  : 'shortTime' }}</p>
<br><p ng-hide="startHour">Enter Valid Time</p>
```

```
app.controller("myVm",function($scope) {

  var vm = $scope;

  vm.startHour = new Date(0);
  vm.startHour.setHours(8);

});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/O0cMSoJr0UwE2ka6NecL?p=preview)